# Create array of strings by replacing multiple words in a start string

Tags: javascript, string, loops, replace, iteration

I'm attempting to create an array of sentences from a single string passed in to my function. The "start string" contains words or phrases that can be replaced with any items in a list stored outside of my function. For example, given

```
var swaps = [
  {name: "animal", replacements: ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]},
  {name: "location", replacements: ["the park", "bed with a cold", "the back seat of the car"]},
  {name: "man", replacements: ["Pete", "Tom", "Robert"]}
]

var sentence = "I saw |man| in |location| with his pet |animal|."
```

I want to create a function that will output

```
[
  "I saw Pete in the park with his pet cat.",
  "I saw Tom in the park with his pet cat.",
  "I saw Robert in the park with his pet cat.",
  "I saw Pete in the park with his pet dog.",
  "I saw Tom in the park with his pet dog.",
  "I saw Robert in the park with his pet dog.",
  "I saw Pete in the park with his pet rabbit.",
  "I saw Tom in the park with his pet rabbit.",
  "I saw Robert in the park with his pet rabbit.",
  "I saw Pete in bed with a cold with his pet cat.",
  "I saw Tom in bed with a cold with his pet cat.",
  "I saw Robert in bed with a cold with his pet cat.",
  "I saw Pete in bed with a cold with his pet dog.",
  "I saw Tom in bed with a cold with his pet dog.",
  "I saw Robert in bed with a cold with his pet dog.",
  "I saw Pete in bed with a cold with his pet rabbit.",
  "I saw Tom in bed with a cold with his pet rabbit.",
  "I saw Robert in bed with a cold with his pet rabbit.",
  "I saw Pete in the back seat of the car with his pet cat.",
  "I saw Tom in the back seat of the car with his pet cat.",
  "I saw Robert in the back seat of the car with his pet cat.",
  "I saw Pete in the back seat of the car with his pet dog.",
  "I saw Tom in the back seat of the car with his pet dog.",
  "I saw Robert in the back seat of the car with his pet dog.",
  "I saw Pete in the back seat of the car with his pet rabbit.",
  "I saw Tom in the back seat of the car with his pet rabbit.",
  "I saw Robert in the back seat of the car with his pet rabbit."
]
```

There can be any number of replacements, not necessarily 3. I guess it needs to be a function that calls itself but I have no idea where to start!

I've tried splitting the string at the pipe character (|) and I can successfully replace the first phrase, but I don't know what to do with the resulting array when I don't know how many more phrases might need replacing.

Thanks so much for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

May be that's what you want.

```js
function generateSentences(swaps, sentence) {
  let sentences = [sentence];
 
  swaps.forEach((swap) => {
    let newSentences = [];
 
    swap.replacements.forEach((replacement) => {
      sentences.forEach((prevSentence) => {
        newSentences.push(prevSentence.replace(`|${swap.name}|`, replacement));
      });
    });
 
    sentences = newSentences;
  });
 
  return sentences;
}
 
var swaps = [
    {name: "animal", replacements: ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]},
    {name: "location", replacements: ["the park", "bed with a cold", "the back seat of the car"]},
    {name: "man", replacements: ["Pete", "Tom", "Robert"]}
  ]
 
  var sentence = "I saw |man| in |location| with his pet |animal|."
 
  var res = generateSentences(swaps,sentence);
  console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can restructure the input, then I'd do it like this:

```js
const strings = [
    ["I saw "],
    ["Pete", "Tom", "Robert"],
    [" in "],
    ["the park", "bed with a cold", "the back seat of the car"],
    [" with his pet "],
    ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"],
    ["."],
];
function multiplyTwoArrays(a, b) {
  return a.flatMap(c => b.map(d => c + d));
}
const result = strings.reduce(multiplyTwoArrays);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much both. I didn't mention that I actually have an entire CSV file of replacement phrases. Using either of your solutions caused a memory overload in my code, but your similar methods put me on the right track.

I realised I can do one phrase at a time, append any new sentences to the end of the array, and go again whilst any pipes remain in any of the sentences. My final function looked like this:

```
function generateQueries(sentence: any, swaps: any) {
  var pipeFirst: any = -1;
  var pipeSecond: any = -1;
  var resStart: any = "";
  var resEnd: any = "";
  var swapWord: any = "";
  var res = [sentence];
  while (res[0].indexOf("|") > -1){
    for (var r = 0; r < res.length; r++){
      pipeFirst = res[r].indexOf("|");
      pipeSecond = res[r].indexOf("|", (pipeFirst + 1));
      resStart = res[r].substr(0, pipeFirst);
      resEnd = res[r].substr(pipeSecond + 1);
      swapWord = res[r].split("|")[1];
      for (var s = 0; s < jsonReps.length ; s++){
        if (jsonReps[s].name === swapWord){
          for (var w = 0; w < jsonReps[s].replacements.length ; w++){
            if (w === 0){
              res[r] = resStart + jsonReps[s].replacements[w] + resEnd;
            }
            else{
              res.push(resStart + jsonReps[s].replacements[w] + resEnd);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

I'm sure there are more succinct methods of getting the start and end of the phrase surrounded by pipes in the sentence, but this works for me in TypeScript!

Thanks again guys :o)